# issues with Mysql python code,when restarting python script after abnormal abort

Tags: python, mysql, sparql

I am writing python code to get movies data from dbpedia and put in MySql database.
presently, my application is having issues and it is hanging in between or if it aborts, then next time I restart, there some issues occur when droping the table and creating table in database.

Is it because last time connection with the database didnt get close?
If so then what can be possible solution to avoid this issue when restarting the application

Answer (score 1):

What python library are you using to access MySQL? If you are using MySQLdb, then to be sure everything is written correctly, you need to use the "close" method of your cursor and the "commit" method of the connection. For example,

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(user="username",pass="password",db="dbname")
cur = conn.cursor()
# Work with your cur object to do what you want
cur.close()
conn.commit()
```

Comment: I am using close and commit functions of MYSQLdb, but my application is crashing or hanging in between, I am debugging these issues but every time I have to restart my system to get script running.

Comment: @user1036348 If it hangs, try connecting to mysql as root (mysql -u root) and running FLUSH TABLES. That will clear the query queue and apply any changes. If that fails, you could try restarting the mysql service.